# Why use <?> in Java

Tags: java, generics

Why would someone want to use `<?>` in Java?

If you are going to use it, why even use generics at all?

Why is `List<?>` better than simply `List` and in what scenario?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Because simply writing `List` gives a compiler warning.

Comment: That's it? Just to be cool and modern?

Comment: @Nambari, I'm aware of the meaning of wildcards. The link is not answering the question.

Comment: No, because `public void foo(List<?> barList)` can accept any `List<Whatever>` (similar to `public void foo(List barList)` but no warning for using raw types). This is not *cool and modern*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: So the difference is a similarity you say...

Comment: One strictly allows `Object` types only, the other allows *anything*. Try reading the duplicate question link or the link @Nambari commented with.